# Run `dbus-send` in a remote system

Tags: linux, ssh, d-bus

I'm trying to run `dbus-send` in a remote system but somehow I'm not able to run it. But the same `dbus-send`, if I run it in the local system, is working fine.

**COMMAND**:

`ssh remote@xx.xx.xx.xxx "dbus-send --print-reply --dest=service.name /object/path object.path.Service.method string:"XYZ""`

How can I run `dbus-send` command from the remote system?

**SYSTEM INFO**

Linux 3.13.0-29-generic Ubuntu i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: What is the error you are getting? since you are inside an SSH session (not a desktop session) `dbus-send` probably cannot find which session bus to connect to - it *may* be enough to set the `DISPLAY` variable to that of the remote session e.g. `"DISPLAY=:0 dbus-send ..."`; otherwise you will need to extract and set the actual `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`

Comment: Actually I'm extracting `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and the value is `unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus` but still i'm not able to execute `dbus-send`

Comment: That looks like a *location* not an actual address value - did you try the `source` command from @chaos's answer?

Comment: @steeldriver: Nope,It's not working.Error: `cat: /var/lib/dbus/machine-id: No such file or directory` `bash: ~/.dbus/session-bus/-0:Permission denied`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dbus-send` needs some evironment variables to connect to the dbus-session. First you need to estimate them. First `ssh` to your machine.

The `$DISPLAY` variable:

```
DISPLAY=$(strings /proc/$(pgrep -n Xorg)/environ | awk -F== '$1 ~ "DISPLAY"{print $2}')
```

The dbus session variables:

```
source ~/.dbus/session-bus/$(cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id)-0
```

Now you can place your `dbus-send` command.

Comment: I'm setting `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`. Along with that do I need to set `DISPLAY` variable also?

Comment: @Thushi Yes, if you don't `X11 initialization failed` would occur.

Comment: I'm using `mutter` window manager.Is that fine with `DISPLAY` variable?

Comment: @Thushi yes, that doesn't matter

Comment: K.But If I run that command I'm getting the following error. `cat: /var/lib/dbus/machine-id: No such file or directory` `bash: ~/.dbus/session-bus/-0:Permission denied`

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -la ~/.dbus/session-bus/`, please?

Comment: If I execute `ls` without `sudo` it shows `cannot open directory ~/.dbus/session-bus/: Permission denied`.So I'm running with `sudo ls -la ~/.dbus/session-bus` and the output is `total 4` `drwx------ 1 root root .` `drwxr-xr-x 1 user user ..` `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1ca7323ca88a4a708dd2e499ee70fc16-0`

Comment: Ok, use this: `source ~/.dbus/session-bus/$(sudo cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id)-0`.

Comment: But in my previous comment I mentioned that `cat: /var/lib/dbus/machine-id: No such file or directory` and I'm getting the same error again.

Comment: Ah, sry. I meant: `sudo cat ~/.dbus/session-bus/1ca7323ca88a4a708dd2e499ee70fc16-0`. There are the variables. Copy them in the shell to set them.

Comment: You mean the command is `source ~/.dbus/session-bus/$(sudo cat ~/.dbus/session-bus/1ca7323ca88a4a708dd2e499ee70fc16-0)-0` ?????

Comment: Can you please help me with this? What ll be the full command?

Comment: @Thushi No, `sudo cat ~/.dbus/session-bus/1ca7323ca88a4a708dd2e499ee70fc16-0` The Output looks like this: http://pastebin.com/ggK7BNyM, yours looks different. Now you see the 3 variables. Copy them in the current shell to set them. Then use the dbus-send commmand again.

Comment: Hmmm...I tried that,it's not working.Actually my `dbus-send` is a part of shell script.And from my remote system I'll execute that `.sh` file.So,I'm setting that variables in that script before calling the `dbus-send`.Is it right way to set the variables inside the `.sh` file?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I would first try it in a shell

Comment: `Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11` I'm getting this error.I set the `DISPLAY` value as you mentioned before running the `dbus-send`

Comment: Are you placing the command with the same user who you want to send the dbus command to? If not, that's the problem. Try it with `sudo dbus-send`

Comment: I tried with `sudo` also,but I'm getting the same error.If I print the `DISPLAY` variable then it is not having any value.It's just showing the blank output for `echo $DISPLAY`.

Comment: Then it's not set. Use `sudo strings /proc/$(sudo pgrep -n Xorg)/environ`. Search for the variable in the output (in my case it's `DISPLAY==:0`) and then set it to that value: `DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: Even I'm having the same value,Setting `DISPLAY=:0` and then running `dbus-send` gives the same error. :(

Comment: I did `ssh` to my remote system and there I'm trying this

Comment: I'm calling the method of my own service created by me and started by `systemd`.Do I need to specify the `pid` of that service to the variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID`? and the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` of that service from `/proc/serivce_pid/environ`????

Comment: `Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-6C1VvbrQOP: Connection refused` I'm getting this error now

Comment: K now I'm running `dbus-send`with `sudo` and i'm getting the following error.`Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name service.name was not provided by any .service files`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16884/discussion-between-chaos-and-thushi).

Comment: Somehow I managed to get the following error.So,what ll be the problem now. :( :( Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.Any Solution for this?

Comment: Finally I found the solution for this.I was running my `dbus-send` command with `sudo` because of that I wasn't able to get the environment variables what I exported before. So,now I'm running this with `sudo -E dbus-send` and it's working fine.Anyhow,thanks for your patience and support :).

Comment: For me `pgrep -n Xorg` didn't work/help. First, I had gnome-shell and not Xorg. Second, In multi-user environment `pgrep -n` returned PID for the wrong process (other user's), so I had to modify it to `-u $(whoami) -x gnome-shell`. Finally, `awk` part didn't really work for me. I had to replace it with `grep -oP 'DISPLAY=\K.*'`. Also, I needed do the same with one extra variable: `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRES`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are tou using a semicolon ? this make a  new command on local host.

try using

```
ssh remote@xx.xx.xx.xxx "dbus-send --print-reply --dest=service.name /object/path object.path.Service.method string:XYZ"
```

Also note, that /object/path is on remote host.

**next try**: try addind /usr/bin (if fact, on remote host, isseu `which dbus-send` to know exact path).

```
ssh remote@xx.xx.xx.xxx "/usr/bin/dbus-send --print-reply --dest=service.name /object/path object.path.Service.method string:XYZ"
```

can you provide error message ?

Comment: Yeah..I tried your solution.Still it is not working for me and edited the question also.